# Check if current time is within availability times, NodeJS

Tags: node.js, datetime, momentjs

I would like to know if the current time (Monday, July 17, 2017 3:21 PM) is within the availability times (which is a JSON object)

The below availabilityTimes can be read as, there is availability on Monday from 7:00 am to 10 am and 1:00 pm and 5:00 pm.
Saturday from 9:00 am to 10 am and 3:00 pm to 5:00 pm and so on.

How could I know if the current time is within the availability, I am using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com).

```
var availabilityTimes = {   
    "Monday": {
        "times": [
            {
                "startTime":"7:00 AM",
                "endTime":"10:00 AM"
            },
            {
                "startTime":"1:00 PM",
                "endTime":"5:00 PM"
            }
        ],
        "weekday": "Monday",
        "available": true
    },
    "Saturday": {
        "times": [
            {
                "startTime":"9:00 AM",
                "endTime":"10:00 AM"
            },
            {
                "startTime":"3:00 PM",
                "endTime":"5:00 PM"
            }
        ],
        "weekday": "Saturday",
        "available": true
    },
    "Tuesday": {
        "times": [
            {
                "startTime":"9:00 AM",
                "endTime":"8:00 PM"
            }
        ],
        "weekday": "Tuesday",
        "available": true
    },
    "Sunday": {
        "times": [
            {
                "startTime":"9:00 AM",
                "endTime":"8:00 PM"
            }
        ],
        "weekday": "Sunday",
        "available": true
    },
    "Friday": {
        "times": [
            {
                "startTime": "9:00 am",
                "endTime": "6:00 pm"
            }
        ],
        "weekday": "Friday",
        "available": true
    },
    "Wednesday": {
        "times": [
            {
                "startTime": "9:00 am",
                "endTime": "6:00 pm"
            }
        ],
        "weekday": "Wednesday",
        "available": true
    },
    "Thursday": {
        "times": [
            {
                "startTime": "9:00 am",
                "endTime": "6:00 pm"
            }
        ],
        "weekday": "Thursday",
        "available": true
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try to do and where did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
var isValid = false;
for(let key in availabilityTimes)
{
    isValid = availabilityTimes[key].weekday === moment().format('dddd');    
    if(isValid)
    {
        if(availabilityTimes[key].times.length == 0)
        {
            isValid = false;
            continue;
        }

        for(let time in availabilityTimes[key].times)
        {
            let startTime = Date.parse("1900-01-01 " + time.startTime);
            let endTime = Date.parse("1900-01-01 " + time.endTime);
            let nowTime = Date.parse("1900-01-01 " + moment().format('HH:mm')); 

            isValid = nowTime >= startTime && nowTime <= endTime;
            if(isValid)
            {   
                break;
            }
        }

        if(isValid)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
console.log(isValid);
```

Hope it helps.

Best Regards,

Hatjhie